# Sprite from BitmapData line

Tags: javascript, bitmapdata, phaser-framework

I have a problem creating a sprite from BitmapData. When i have a rectangular shape, the sprite is created without an issue, but when the bitmapData is just a line, the sprite is just empty.

```js
bmd = this.game.add.bitmapData(this.line.width, this.line.height);

//This works fine:
bmd.ctx.rect(0, 0, 32, 32);
bmd.ctx.fillStyle = "#0f0";
bmd.ctx.fill();
var platform = this.game.add.sprite(this.line.midPoint().x, this.line.midPoint().y, bmd);

//This doesn't work
bmd.ctx.this.lineWidth = "8";
bmd.ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
bmd.ctx.moveTo(this.startPoint.x, this.startPoint.y);
bmd.ctx.lineTo(this.endPoint.x, this.endPoint.y);
bmd.ctx.stroke();
var platform = this.game.add.sprite(this.line.midPoint().x, this.line.midPoint().y, bmd);
```

Is there a know issue or do i have a horrible mistake in my code?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it.

```js
Game.prototype.create = function(){
  this.bmd = this.game.add.bitmapData(this.game.width-20, this.game.height);
  this.bmd.ctx.beginPath();
  this.bmd.ctx.lineWidth = "4";
  this.bmd.ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  this.bmd.ctx.stroke();
  this.platform = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, this.bmd);  
};

Game.prototype.draw = function(){
  this.bmd.clear();
  this.bmd.ctx.beginPath();
  this.bmd.ctx.moveTo(this.startPoint.x, this.startPoint.y);
  this.bmd.ctx.lineTo(this.endPoint.x , this.endPoint.y);
  this.bmd.ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  this.bmd.ctx.stroke(); 
  this.bmd.ctx.closePath();
  this.bmd.render();  
}
```

It turns out i should've added the sprite once and then just re-render it.